# Hosting multiple website on my server

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain, bind

Currently I have one site, the files are in my /home/www/ directory and the domain records point toward the IP of my server. That works fine.

I would like to host another site, with a different domain name. If I create a new folder in 'home' (wwwx for arguments sake) and put the new sites files in this, how could I set it so my new domain points to this folder?

Answer (score 1):

When you set up the new domain in Apache, one of the items you have to specify is DocumentRoot - that is where you'll tell Apache where to find the actual web site on disk.

Comment: How do I set up the domain? Previously I have just used CloudNS to configure my nameservers and then pointed my domain toward them on the registrar's site. I haven't touched apache for it.

Comment: @Euskadi Then perhaps it's time to read the Apache manual.

Comment: I'm sure if I studied the entire Apache manual I would find the answer for this and many other problems. Unfortunately I don't have the knowledge or time, so I am asking for someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks for your attempt at helping all the same.

Comment: @Euskadi - you really need to become familiar with Apache. You don't need to read the entire manual, but you do need to read some of it. To start, go to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html. If you don't ever want to read the manual at all because you don't have the time, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at VirtualHosts, I wasn't sure if it was appropriate since I didn't have to change anything in my apache2.conf file to get my current site working - and I don't want to jeopardise that.

Comment: I do not have 'DocumentRoot' in my apache2.conf file?